# Error: Access Denied, on the main page, can see other pages sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-2010

Error: Access Denied, on the main page, can see other pages, 
Current User 
You are currently signed in as:  amark@microsoft.com
Sign in as a different user
 SharePoint online
funny can see the subsite but not the main page, please anyone has an idea?

Comment: Did some break security inheritance on the home page and remove you from the permission set? Are you a SCA in the site collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it was sysadmin who had removed all the users from the homepage, never thought of that, he should go to jail :)